# Customizing Zsh + Oh My Zsh but can't get updates

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I am a newbie with Zsh + Oh My Zsh and have my prompt set to randomly choose between a couple of themes.

`ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "kafeitu" "avit")`

However, I've customized these a bit to make them more like the way I want them.

A side-effect of this is that now, when I get prompted to update Zsh, I cannot:

```
[oh-my-zsh] Would you like to update? [Y/n] Y
Updating Oh My Zsh
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
There was an error updating. Try again later?
```

How can I have customized themes and still maintain the repo such  that I can pull down updates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out there's a custom folder at `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom` directory just for this purpose.

To customize one of the many themes, you just copy a theme in the main theme directory at `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes` to `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes` and edit it as you like.  The setting in `.zshrc` for `ZSH_THEME="[theme name]"` will look into this custom area first before looking in the main themes folder.

Documentation: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Customization#overriding-and-adding-themes